# Apache Shiro salt hashed password

Tags: hash, shiro, sha256

I need to salt a hashed(SHA-256) password using Apache Shiro. I used the following method, but it uses plainText password as a parameter. But I need to get an alredy hashed password from the frontend and salt it and store in the server side. Otherwise if I use the following method I will have to pass the plain password all the way through frontend, which is not secure. So please suggest me a way to overcome this problem.

```
String hashedPassword = new Sha256Hash(plainTextPassword, salt);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot salt the password after it has been hashed. Salting works by combining the salt with the plain text password, and hashing the entire thing. This is why Shiro's Sha256Hash requires you to give it the plain text password.

It is common to pass the plain text password from the front end to the service layer as long as this communication is secure (e.g. HTTPS for web UIs). The only thing you should not do is store the plain text password in a database (which a correctly configured Shiro will not do) because your database may be compromised.

When passing the plain text password from the front end to your service, it will only exist in memory for a short time before being garbage collected. To obtain the password someone would have to either break your SSL connection (in which case you are screwed anyway) or compromise your server and dump the memory (in which case you are screwed anyway).

Comment: By the way, hashing the password on the front end is no more secure because anyone able to intercept the hash could spoof a log in to your site. This is why the only way to make it secure is to encrypt the transport layer with SSL i.e. use HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! Appreciate your help.